# How to run it weaviate after setting embbeded client

Tags: weaviate

I am first time using weaviate and typsecript as well.

I have set all options in embeded client:

```
const client: EmbeddedClient = weaviate.client(
  new EmbeddedOptions({
    port: 7878,
    version: '1.18.1',
    env: {
      QUERY_DEFAULTS_LIMIT: 50,
      DEFAULT_VECTORIZER_MODULE: 'text2vec-openai',
    },
  }),
  // weaviate-ts-client ConnectionParams
  {
    scheme: 'http',
    host: '127.0.0.1:7878',
  }
);
```

My question is how do i run the code in ts.
I am using visual studio code as editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Duda from Weaviate here :)

I have answered this question also in our forums: https://forum.weaviate.io/t/how-to-run-weaviaate/533/2

There is a nice example on how to run Weaviate Embedded here:
https://github.com/weaviate/typescript-embedded/tree/main/examples/embedded

Considering you have those files under the same folder, you will need to install the dependencies:

```
npm i
```

now transform typescript code into javascript

```
tsc
```

and run it:

```
node dist/idex.js
```

This is the expected output:

```
node dist/index.js 
Weaviate binary: /home/dudanogueira/.cache/weaviate-embedded-latest
Data path: /home/dudanogueira/.local/share/weaviate
Trying to connect to embedded db... {"errno":-111,"code":"ECONNREFUSED","syscall":"connect","address":"127.0.0.1","port":9898}
Started /home/dudanogueira/.cache/weaviate-embedded-latest @ 127.0.0.1:9898 -- process ID 518836
{"action":"startup","default_vectorizer_module":"none","level":"info","msg":"the default vectorizer modules is set to \"none\", as a result all new schema classes without an explicit vectorizer setting, will use this vectorizer","time":"2023-08-14T14:23:27-03:00"}
{"action":"startup","auto_schema_enabled":true,"level":"info","msg":"auto schema enabled setting is set to \"true\"","time":"2023-08-14T14:23:27-03:00"}
{"level":"warning","msg":"Multiple vector spaces are present, GraphQL Explore and REST API list objects endpoint module include params has been disabled as a result.","time":"2023-08-14T14:23:27-03:00"}
{"action":"grpc_startup","level":"info","msg":"grpc server listening at [::]:50051","time":"2023-08-14T14:23:27-03:00"}
{"action":"restapi_management","level":"info","msg":"Serving weaviate at http://127.0.0.1:9898","time":"2023-08-14T14:23:27-03:00"}
connected to embedded db!

Embedded DB started

{"action":"hnsw_vector_cache_prefill","count":1000,"index_id":"wine_Z1lw0YT8yNDP","level":"info","limit":1000000000000,"msg":"prefilled vector cache","time":"2023-08-14T14:23:28-03:00","took":134258}
{
  class: 'Wine',
  creationTimeUnix: 1692033808364,
  id: '43afc241-0846-40ff-a1dc-4f24439f9345',
  lastUpdateTimeUnix: 1692033808364,
  properties: { description: 'Smooth taste', name: 'Pinot noir' }
}
{
  deprecations: null,
  objects: [
    {
      class: 'Wine',
      creationTimeUnix: 1692033808364,
      id: '43afc241-0846-40ff-a1dc-4f24439f9345',
      lastUpdateTimeUnix: 1692033808364,
      properties: [Object],
      vectorWeights: null
    }
  ],
  totalResults: 1
}
{
  hostname: 'http://127.0.0.1:9898',
  modules: {
    'generative-openai': {
      documentationHref: 'https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/completions',
      name: 'Generative Search - OpenAI'
    },
    'qna-openai': {
      documentationHref: 'https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/completions',
      name: 'OpenAI Question & Answering Module'
    },
    'ref2vec-centroid': {},
    'text2vec-cohere': {
      documentationHref: 'https://docs.cohere.ai/embedding-wiki/',
      name: 'Cohere Module'
    },
    'text2vec-huggingface': {
      documentationHref: 'https://huggingface.co/docs/api-inference/detailed_parameters#feature-extraction-task',
      name: 'Hugging Face Module'
    },
    'text2vec-openai': {
      documentationHref: 'https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/embeddings/what-are-embeddings',
      name: 'OpenAI Module'
    }
  },
  version: '1.20.5'
}

Stopping...
Embedded db @ PID 518836 successfully stopped
Exiting...
{"action":"restapi_management","level":"info","msg":"Shutting down... ","time":"2023-08-14T14:23:28-03:00"}
{"action":"restapi_management","level":"info","msg":"Stopped serving weaviate at http://127.0.0.1:9898","time":"2023-08-14T14:23:28-03:00"}
```

**Note:** Weaviate Embedded is [marked as Experimental](https://weaviate.io/developers/weaviate/installation/embedded) as of now.